# MediaRecorder.stop() で NullPointerException が返ってくる

Tags: android, java, nullpointerexception

現在ダイアログ上のスタートボタンを押すことで録音を開始し、ストップボタンを押すと別の保存確認ダイアログが表示され、そこで保存ボタンを押すと録音した音声が保存されるプログラムを組んでいます。しかし、録音を終了すると、 `RecDialog` クラスの `stopRecording` メソッド内の `mRecorder.stop()` で `NullPointerException`が返ってきます。色々とトライしてみても依然結果は同じです。これはなぜなのでしょうか？ `DialogFragment` を使っているあたり何か関係があるのでしょうか？

すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

*RecDialog*:

```java
public class RecDialog extends DialogFragment {
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rec_dialog, null);

        final ImageButton recordButton = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.recButton);
        recordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mRecButtonClick) {
                    recordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone_on);
                    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    startRecording();
                    mRecButtonClick = true;
                } else {
                    recordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.microphone_off);
                    mRecButtonClick = false;
                    showDialogBroadcast();
                }
        });
    }

    public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            DialogFragment dialog = new SaveDialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    }

    public void showDialogBroadcast() {
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("show_saveDialog");
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }

    public void startRecording() {
        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test");
        try {
            mAudiofile = File.createTempFile("voice", ".3gp", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return;
        }
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mAudiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mRecorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording(String fileName) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        addVoiceToMediaLibrary(fileName);
    }
```

*SaveDialog*:

```java
RecDialog recDialog = new RecDialog();
recDialog.stopRecording(editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: startRecordingを呼び出しているrecDialogとstopRecordingを呼び出しているrecDialogは同じオブジェクトを使用しておりますか？
（老婆心ながら、RecDialogの中でmRecorderを生成すると、RecDialogのオブジェクトの生存期間にmRecorderが引っ張られるので、RecDialogのコンストラクタから別クラスで生成したmRecorderを渡して上げるような形がいいかな？なんて思いました。）

Comment: 提示されているSaveDialog実装だと、単に`mRecorder==null`となってしまいNullPointerExceptionが発生します。

Comment: user3009331さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。startRecordingを呼び出しているrecDialogとstopRecordingを呼び出しているrecDialogは異なるオブジェクトを使用しております‌​。すみません、初歩的なことが分かっておらず質問させていただきたいのですが、ということはSaveDialogでRecDilogのインスタンスを生成した時点でRecDialogに存在していたmRecorderが消滅するということでしょうか？

Comment: yohjpさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。初歩的なことだと思うのですが、mRecorderがなぜnullになるかが分かりません。。。なのでオブジェクトの生成方法を変えてみたいと思います。

Comment: start と stop それぞれで、「RecDialog recDialog = new RecDialog();」としているから、ではないでしょうか。start を実行した recDialog インスタンスと stop を実行する recDialog インスタンスは別物ですので、その中にある mRecorder も別のインスタンスになってしまい、stop 実行時の recDialog.mRecorder は null のままとなります。

Comment: heliac2001さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。インスタンスが別物によることが原因なのですね。帰宅後にその辺を修正してみたいと思います。

Comment: heliac2001 の指摘の通りだと思います。 ダイアログを作成している部分のコードがあると、コード付きで回答がしやすくなると思いますよ。

Comment: Hiroshi Yamamotoさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りもう少し詳しくコードを載せたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

質問内容＋質問者さんコメントからの推測ですが、概ね下記のようなコード構造となっているのでは？

```
class RecDialog {
  private MediaRecorder mRecorder;  // <-- インスタンス変数
  //...

  public void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    // ...
    mRecorder.start();
  }

  public void stopRecording(String fileName) {
    mRecorder.stop();
    // ...
  }
}

class SaveDialog {
  //...

  public void startOperation() {
    RecDialog recDialog = new RecDialog();  // (1)
    recDialog.startRecording();
  }

  public void stopOperation() {
    RecDialog recDialog = new RecDialog();  // (2)
    recDialog.stopRecording(editText.getText().toString());
  }
}
```

`mRecorder`を`RecDialog`クラスの「インスタンス変数」としているならば、`RecDialog`クラスのインスタンスが破棄されると同時に`mRecorder`が指す先も破棄されます。前掲コードだと(1)と(2)は`RecDialog`クラスの**異なる**インスタンスを指すため、(1)で設定した`mRecorder`の値が(2)に引き継がれることはありません。(2)では`mRecorder`は未初期化(`null`)のままであり、`null`に対して「インスタンスメソッド」`stopRecording`を呼び出そうとした結果、NullPointerException例外が発生します。

これはAndroid環境固有の振る舞いではなくプログラミング言語Javaの仕様によるものですから、この辺りのJavaの基礎を再確認されるのが良いかと思います。（普通のJava入門書であれば必ず言及されているはずです。キーワードとしては「インスタンス変数」、「インスタンスメソッド」が該当します。）

Comment: はい、MediaRecorderのインスタンス変数をフィールドで宣言して、startRecordingメソッド内でインスタンスを生成しているのですが、SaveDialogクラス内ではRecDialogは一度しかインスタンス生成していませんでした。すみません。となるとオブジェクトの生存期間（？）が関係してくるのでしょうか？

Comment: **短い答え**：関係します。**長い答え**：これ以上の詳細説明は本サイトの範疇を超えてしまう（と私は考えるので）、本件に関するの追加回答は控えさせてもらいます。Java言語でのオブジェクト指向の基礎的な理解で混乱されているように見受けられます。もしJava言語の入門書をお持ちであれば、もう一度最初から読み直し、ぜひ色々コードを書いて試行錯誤してみてください。その手の本に縁がなかったのであれば、書籍による基礎知識の習得を強くお勧めします。ネット上にはさまさまな情報にあふれていますが、断片的である事が多く体系的な知識には繋がりにくいです。

Comment: 了解しました。やはり基礎からもう一度学習することに致します。親切な対応とても感謝しています。ありがとうございました。